# Need to establish an SSH tunnel in Node.js or do it on the server

Tags: node.js, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I'm going to connect to a remote database using an SSH tunnel. Currently, I'm not sure how long the server is alive, but I will check with my provider.

However, is it safe to assume that I will be able to connect to the database by running this command: `ssh -fNg -L 1337:database-name:3306 user@ssh-server.com` once on the client? Or do I need to establish a connection all the time? I know there exist some npm modules to connect via SSH.

Thanks in advance!